What actor has portrayed the American president the most number of times?
Which actor has acted as president of the USA in the most distinct number of appearances?

Ronald Reagan acted as the United States president every day for eight years straight, except for a few days when he was undergoing surgery.

Touche.  You really do deserve the cred.

But did Reagan ever act as president while he was an actor?

Francis Ford, brother of auteur director John Ford.
From here and here.

Yet, none of these aforementioned names compares to the classic actor Francis Ford, the brother of the iconic director John Ford, who appeared as Abraham Lincoln a whopping nine times over just four years from 1912 to 1915.


His first depiction of the 16th US President came in 1912 when he appeared in the short drama On Secret Service, helmed by Thomas H. Ince. Yet, it was the following year that Ford really embraced the role of Lincoln, appearing as the President a total of six times in When Lincoln Paid, The Battle of Bull Run, From Rail Splitter to President, The Toll of War, With Lee in Virginia and The Great Sacrifice.


Two years later, Ford would cap off his record by playing Lincoln twice more in The Heart of Maryland and The Heart of Lincoln.

